# Netbeans Run->Stop Build does not stop the running java processes

Tags: netbeans, netty

I'm using Netbeans 7.1.2 on Mac OS X Lion 10.7.3.

I have a simple java server (using netty) project and after I build and run the project then try to stop the running by Run->Stop Build it does not terminate the java server process.

For example, my server app uses port 8080 and even after I stop running from the netbeans the port 8080 is in use and the app keeps running. I have to manually kill the java process from activity monitor.

What's the correct procedure to end the running app started by Netbeans?

Greatly appreciate your help. Thanks in advanced.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the documentation: http://netty.io/docs/stable/guide/html/. Scroll down to section 9.  Shutting Down Your Application.

Your main app ahs to look something like:

```
package org.jboss.netty.example.time;
public class TimeServer {
    static final ChannelGroup allChannels = new DefaultChannelGroup("time-server"(35));
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        ...
        ChannelFactory factory = ...;
        ServerBootstrap bootstrap = ...;
        ...
        Channel channel = bootstrap.bind(...);
        allChannels.add(channel);

        ...

        // Shutdown code
        ChannelGroupFuture future = allChannels.close();
        future.awaitUninterruptibly();
        factory.releaseExternalResources();
    }
}
```

You handler needs:

```
public void channelOpen(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, ChannelStateEvent e) {
    TimeServer.allChannels.add(e.getChannel());
}
```

You have to:
1. Store all your channels in a `ChannelGroup`
2. When shutting down, close all channel and release resources.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I'm simply using the HttpSnoopServer given in the netty examples (org.jboss.netty.example.http.snoop). And I see the following code in the server handler. 
    ChannelFuture future = e.getChannel().write(response);

        // Close the non-keep-alive connection after the write operation is done.
        if (!keepAlive)
        {
            future.addListener(ChannelFutureListener.CLOSE);
        } `

Isn't it similar to what you have specified there?